Transition from 8-byte to 11-byte instruction lengths for local variables
Notice these C++ local variable instruction lengths are 8-bytes within the red box
48 c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00
...

However, the instruction lengths are 11-bytes within the green box
48 c7 85 78 ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 
...

https://godbolt.org/z/bTsxx63rT

Background
I was working on some shellcode that required patching API addresses but noticed errors because the local variable instructions lengths jumped from 8 to 11 bytes. Anyhow, thru trial and error, to enforce all the instructions to be 11 bytes, I added a local array
char enforce_mov_long_form[128];

to avoid accessing locals in the range [rbp-0x8] to [rbp-0x80]
DWORD WINAPI shellcode_start(void)
{

    char enforce_mov_long_form[128];

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    QWORD           start_shellcode          = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    DWORD           sizeofshellcode          = 0xAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           start_shellcode_injector = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    DWORD           pid_injector             = 0xAAAAAAAA;

    QWORD           WinExec                  = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           Sleep                    = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           CreateToolhelp32Snapshot = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           Process32First           = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           Process32Next            = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           CloseHandle              = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           OpenProcess              = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           VirtualAllocEx           = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           VirtualFreeEx            = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           WriteProcessMemory       = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           CreateRemoteThread       = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           CompareStringA           = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    QWORD           GetCurrentProcessId      = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

Questions
Why is there a sudden transition from 8-byte to 11-byte instruction lengths for local variables?
Are there any micro optimizations gained by confining local variables within [rbp-0x8] to [rbp-0x80]?

Because the 8 byte instruction only supports a sign extended 8 bit offset it can only encode -0x80 to +0x7F

So when the offset from rbp falls outside the 8-bit range, it requires a 32-bit displacement which explains the extra bytes. Is that correct? Thanks!

Yes that is correct.

It wasn't done here but there is a note in the x64 function prolog conventions documentation that you can use an offset framepointer and "Using an offset allows more of the fixed allocation area to be addressed with one-byte offsets."

Promoting comments to answer:
x86-64 addressing modes encode the displacement as either a signed 8-bit (1 byte) or signed 32-bit (4 bytes) value, which in either case is sign-extended to 64 bits.  Since the range of a signed 8-bit integer is [-128..127] or [-0x80..0x7f], displacements outside this range must use the 32-bit form instead, making the instruction three bytes longer.
For more on how addressing modes are encoded, see https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding and Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes).

Thanks! Although, I'm still not sure why it wouldn't use a 16-bit displacement instead of 32-bit.

@vengy: There's no option for a 16-bit displacement in 32- or 64-bit mode (only in 16-bit real or vm86 mode).

@vengy: (Well, in 32-bit mode you can use the 0x67 address-size override to use a 16-bit addressing mode, including a 16-bit displacement.  But then the entire address is truncated to 16 bits, so you can only address the low 64K of a segment, making the feature next to useless.)
